# Validation of DropDownListFor element in MVC3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I use jQuery Unobrtusive Validation with MVC3 to validate a `DropDownListFor` form element, but it doesn't work.

It validates very well if I modify `DropDownListFor` to `TextBoxFor` - and it also validates the other fields of the form. I have multiple `DropDownListFor` elements, based on what's available in the database. Thus the loop.

Here's some of my code:

**ViewModel:**

```
public class ParentViewModel  
{ 
// some other stuff here public
List<Children> Children { get; set; } 
}

public class ChildrenViewModel  
{ 
    public SelectList PossibleNames { get; set; } 
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select a name")] 
    public int ChosenNameId { get; set; } 
}
```

**View:**

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Children.Count; i++) 
{
@Html.LabelFor(model => modell.Children[i].ChosenNameId, "Name")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => modell.Children[i].ChosenNameId)
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => modell.Children[i].ChosenNameId,
Model.Children[i].PossibleNames, "Choose a name") 
}
```

Hopefully these extracts are enough to identify the error...

Any hints on why this doesnt work?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Select a name")] 
public int ChosenNameId { get; set; }
```

by:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Select a name")] 
public int? ChosenNameId { get; set; }
```

Notice the nullable integer that is being used. You should be using a nullable type when binding a dropdownlist that can have a non-selected value.

Comment: Hmm, it still doesn't work. The name isn't nullable; it needs to be selected.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out myself. This seems to be a bug in MVC3, which causes **collections of selectlists not to be validated**. The issue has been discussed several times before, for instance:

- http://forums.asp.net/t/1649193.aspx/1/10
- [ASP.NET MVC 3 - Validation Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881583/asp-net-mvc-3-validation-question)

Personally, I solved it by simply manually adding `data-val-required` and `data-val` manually.