# .Net MVC 3 Razor example of using DdUovFor workaround to fix DropDownListFor validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, razor, drop-down-menu

I came across the following code in [this post](http://forums.asp.net/post/4286389.aspx) which is supposed to fix validation for DropDownListFor. However, I am unsure what value to pass from the view for the parameter:

```
this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper
```

What should be passed for this value? Could you provide an example of using this in the view? This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881583/asp-net-mvc-3-validation-question) where no example is provided.

```
 [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1011:ConsiderPassingBaseTypesAsParameters", Justification = "Users cannot use anonymous methods with the LambdaExpression type")]
        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1006:DoNotNestGenericTypesInMemberSignatures", Justification = "This is an appropriate nesting of generic types")]
        public static MvcHtmlString DdUovFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, string optionLabel, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
        {
            if (expression == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");
            }

            ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

            IDictionary<string, object> validationAttributes = htmlHelper
                .GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression), metadata);

            if (htmlAttributes == null)
                htmlAttributes = validationAttributes;
            else
                htmlAttributes = htmlAttributes.Concat(validationAttributes).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);

            return SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(htmlHelper, expression, selectList, optionLabel, htmlAttributes);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass anything, simply call @Html.DdUovFor ignoring that parameter.

See extension methods:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

The htmlHelper is the instance of Html in @Html.. automatically that it refers to in the View.