# Any way to not have to retroactively produce these data- attributes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper, html.dropdownlistfor

This `Html.DropDownListFor` helper should produce the data- attributes but fails to if there is any nesting. So this fails to produce them:

```
@( 
 Html.DropDownListFor( 
  m => m.P[0].CId, 
  new SelectList(
   Model.Cs.Values, 
   "Id", "DisplayFields", Model.Cs.StartValue), 
  Model.Cs.Message 
 ) 
)
```

However, this produces them just fine:

```
@( 
 Html.DropDownListFor( 
  m => m.CId, 
  new SelectList(
   Model.Cs.Values, 
   "Id", "DisplayFields", Model.Cs.StartValue), 
  Model.Cs.Message 
 ) 
)
```

How can I avoid having to go back and define the missing data- attributes manually with some script?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4881583/1026459

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way but to retroactively assign these missing data- attributes when using the `@Html.DropDownListFor` helper. The important ones to keep are `data-val = "true"`, `data-val-required="This value is required"`. Furthermore, a span for the validation with `data-valmsg-replace="true"`, `data-valmsg-for="ID OF SELECT ELEMENT"`, `class="field-validation-valid"`.

However, if you choose to use a custom helper then this can be avoided. This can be seen here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1649193.aspx/1/10 where the answer details how to extend the DropDownListFor helper. This is the code they use:

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1006:DoNotNestGenericTypesInMemberSignatures", Justification = "This is an appropriate nesting of generic types")]
    public static MvcHtmlString DdUovFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList)
    {
        return DdUovFor(htmlHelper, expression, selectList, null /* optionLabel */, null /* htmlAttributes */);
    }


    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1006:DoNotNestGenericTypesInMemberSignatures", Justification = "This is an appropriate nesting of generic types")]
    public static MvcHtmlString DdUovFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return DdUovFor(htmlHelper, expression, selectList, null /* optionLabel */, new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
    }


    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1006:DoNotNestGenericTypesInMemberSignatures", Justification = "This is an appropriate nesting of generic types")]
    public static MvcHtmlString DdUovFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        return DdUovFor(htmlHelper, expression, selectList, null /* optionLabel */, htmlAttributes);
    }


    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1006:DoNotNestGenericTypesInMemberSignatures", Justification = "This is an appropriate nesting of generic types")]
    public static MvcHtmlString DdUovFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, string optionLabel)
    {
        return DdUovFor(htmlHelper, expression, selectList, optionLabel, null /* htmlAttributes */);
    }


    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1006:DoNotNestGenericTypesInMemberSignatures", Justification = "This is an appropriate nesting of generic types")]
    public static MvcHtmlString DdUovFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, string optionLabel, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return DdUovFor(htmlHelper, expression, selectList, optionLabel, new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
    }


    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1011:ConsiderPassingBaseTypesAsParameters", Justification = "Users cannot use anonymous methods with the LambdaExpression type")]
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1006:DoNotNestGenericTypesInMemberSignatures", Justification = "This is an appropriate nesting of generic types")]
    public static MvcHtmlString DdUovFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, string optionLabel, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        if (expression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");
        }


        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);


        IDictionary<string, object> validationAttributes = htmlHelper
            .GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression), metadata);


        if (htmlAttributes == null)
            htmlAttributes = validationAttributes;
        else
            htmlAttributes = htmlAttributes.Concat(validationAttributes).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);


        return SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(htmlHelper, expression, selectList, optionLabel, htmlAttributes);
    }
```